# JDBC encoding Python: Comma delimited Pandas column names

Tags: jdbc, encoding, character-encoding, driver

I attempted to read in data via JDBC connection from Spark using JayDeBeApi and my pandas.read_sql contains columns with comma delimited names:

e.g. (A,p,p,l,e,s)....(P,e,a,r,s)

Df = pd.read_sql(query, jdbc_conn)

I realize this is encoding problem but the JDBC api doesn’t have encoding or option methods to set encoding like pyodbc. Is there a way to pass encoding argument to url or api?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when connecting to an Oracle database from JayDeBeApi. This was because the path to the JDK was not properly set. Now that it is fixed, the parsing issue is gone.